# Unix Grep Exact Match Issue

Tags: shell, grep

I have a text file `Input.txt`

```
7643 , PHP/5.6.16
7649 , PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21
10230 , PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3
14415 , PHP/5.6.17
14414 , PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
24536 , PHP/5.3.3
24534 , PHP/5.3.3
14204 , PHP/5.4.45
1292 , PHP/5.5.33-1~dotdeb+7.1
5639 , PHP/5.3.3
5635 , PHP/5.5.31
8480 , PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2
8484 , PHP/5.3.29
8486 , PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
355  , PHP/5
```

When I grep for the exact PHP version 5, It returns all the lines containing `PHP/5`.

I tried using:

```
grep -w "PHP/5" Input.txt
```

How to get the exact string `PHP/5` from the input?

Comment: `grep "PHP/5$" Input.txt`?

Comment: @Biffen Thanks mate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -w "PHP/5[[:blank:]]*$" file

355  , PHP/5
```

`[[:blank:]]*$` will match 0 or more spaces followed by end of line after `PHP/5`.

Comment: Yeah, Got it. Thanks Anubhava !

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with:

```
grep -w "PHP/5\s*$" myIn
```